# Is the span of $\{ \sin n\pi x \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ dense in $L^2[0,1]$?

Tags: fourier-series

The answers in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286512/why-is-sinn-pi-x-n-in-mathbb-n-dense-in-l20-1) say otherwise, but I'm not sure if they are commenting on the set $\{ \sin n \pi x\}$ itself or its span. I was wondering if the following argument was valid:

> We know that Fourier series are dense in $L^2[-1, 1]$, and that in particular, for $f$ in $L^2$, its Fourier series converges to $f$ (with respect to the $L^2$ norm). We can extend any $g \in L^2[0,1]$  to an odd function $h$ on $[-1, 1]$, and the Fourier series of an odd function is a sine series, so $h(x)\sim \sum \hat{h}(n) \sin(n \pi x)$. Then restricting $h$ back to $[0, 1]$, we still have $h(x)=g(x)\sim \sum \hat{h}(n) \sin(n \pi x)$ in the $L^2$ metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct and the span is dense. The question in your link is about denseness of the sequence itself, not its span.